# How do I fill the holes in concrete to reattach a curtain rod?

Tags: walls, concrete, drill, anchor

I am very, very new to this DIY thing, so be gentle.

A bedroom curtain rod popped out of this concrete wall with a surface material which I don't recognize.  The rod holds fairly heavy blackout curtains.

The rod is fine, the wall is not. At the very least I would like to fill/patch these holes. There isn't much room so ideally I would also like to reuse the area to drill in and reinstall the rod with new anchors and screws.  I have a hammer drill, anchors, and screws.

Finally, optionally, I'd like to fix that edge but I have *no* idea what that material is on the surface.

The photo is of the right side, the left looks the same.  Happy to provide any additional details.

Thank you all so much in advance.

[image]

Comment: Was there any sort of anchor? How did the rod even get secured to the wall?

Comment: Yes, there were anchors and screws. I don't know who installed it or how it popped out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to use one of these drop-in anchors with an embed sucket. Enlarge the existing hole, if it is smaller than the sucket, and install the sucket with recommended adhesive. If the existing hole is larger than the sucket, clean the hole and fill it with mortar paste and the sucket. Do not install the curtain rod holder until the adhesive/mortar has fully cured. https://www.globalindustrial.com/c/fasteners/Anchors

[image]

For the edge, I'll just paint it over.

Comment: That sounds like something I can do. Is the mortar paste something I can buy at a hardware store or is that cement and water mix?  Or something else? Thank you

Comment: Yes. Just tell the store clerk the purpose, he/she will lead you to the suitable product. better to get a product having non-shrink, fast set properties that will be of great help.

Comment: "*Just tell the store clerk the purpose, he/she will lead you to the suitable product*"  MAYBE !

Comment: @r13 thank you for that, appreciate it

Comment: @Alaska Man it's true, you never know where a clerk will lead you. Do you know of a suitable product, given the purposes? Thanks!

Comment: To my experience, you shall be able to find satisfactory cement-based filler material from both HD and Crafty Beaver. The clerks at the lumber yard are quite up to tasks.

Comment: Also, don't forget to print out the picture and take it with you, the stores might have a similar product in stock, or may offer other suggestions along with the filler.

Comment: @r13 thank you again (I don't seem to be able to tag you)

Comment: You are welcome. Read all of the specifications and instructions carefully so you won't need to redo it again. Good luck with the repair.